# How to get analytics api to call my callback (which isn't in global scope)? (Using angular)

Tags: angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope, google-analytics-api

I am using analytics API

using: `<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleAnalyticsAPILoaded"></script>`

This is great, but the callback only works if the function sites in the global scope. How can I get a callback to be called from within a function, or an instance of a function.

Or ideally, inside my angular JS controller?

E.g:

```
function ReportsCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.analyticsIsReady = false;
    $scope.analyticsInitStatus = '';

    //$scope.originCompositionChart = new Chart__('originCompositionChart', reportsClient.getOriginCompositionData, true, false);
    $scope.originCompositionChart = new Chart__('originCompositionChart', null, true, false);
    $scope.charts = new Array($scope.originCompositionChart);

    $scope.showIncludedGraphs = function () {
        console.log('show included');
    };

    var js = document.createElement("script");
    js.type = "text/javascript";
    js.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleAnalyticsAPILoaded';
    document.body.appendChild(js);

    this.analyticsInitialiserClient = new AnalyticsInitialiserClient__();

    this.handleAnalyticsAPILoaded = function () {
        console.log('waaa');
    };
}
```

Comment: Why you need to call a function inside a clousure? is that what you are looking for is just to trigger a method inside the controller once is loaded the API?

Comment: Yip that's what I'm after

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't be terrible, IMHO, to put the callback on the window, in this situation. That said, I'd probably move this code to a service, a more conceptually appropriate place to interact with third-party code.

```
function Analytics($rootScope) { // define as a service on the module
    var js = document.createElement("script");
    js.type = "text/javascript";
    js.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleAnalyticsAPILoaded';
    document.body.appendChild(js);

    // Isolate access to global Google library
    window.handleAnalyticsAPILoaded = (function () {
        // Do API Loaded things
        this.analyticsIsReady = true;

        // Tell Angular to run the digest loop, updating everything
        $rootScope.$digest();

        // Clean up the global handler
        delete window.handleAnalyticsAPILoaded;
    }).bind(this); // Or use var this = _this, if you target older browsers.

    this.analyticsIsReady = false;
    this.analyticsInitStatus = '';
}

function ReportsCtrl($scope, Analytics) {
    $scope.analyticsIsReady = Analytics.analyticsIsReady;
    $scope.analyticsInitStatus = Analytics.analyticsInitStatus;

    $scope.originCompositionChart = new Chart__('originCompositionChart', null, true, false);
    $scope.charts = new Array($scope.originCompositionChart);


    $scope.$watch('analyticsIsReady', function(){
        // Do analyticsReady stuff
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access inside a clousure from the global scope. Instead if you want to trigger some process inside the controller from an outside scope there are other ways.

There is a trick to access to the controller scope. When you declare the HTML which will have a controller, angular attach to it a method scope which returns the scope of the controller.

Let's suppose that the controller is declared in an HTML element with id=MyCtr

```
<div data-ng-app>
    <div data-ng-controller="ReportsCtrl" id="MyCtr">
Example calling from outside
    </div>
</div>
```

In your controller scope there is a method attached:

```
$scope.handleAnalyticsAPILoaded = function () {
    console.log('waaa');
};
```

Then you can trigger any method attached to the controller using this:

```
angular.element(document.getElementById("MyCtr")).scope().handleAnalyticsAPILoaded();
```

So if you use a callback in the onload like this

```
function handleAnalyticsAPILoaded() {
    angular.element(document.getElementById("MyCtr")).scope().handleAnalyticsAPILoaded();
}
```

Then when the

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleAnalyticsAPILoaded"></script>
```

is loaded the controller method will be trigged showing the fancy waaa message

Here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/siliconball/nFnfQ/1/

Comment: Hi user, thank you. I have an issue with this though. I don't like the idea of my service callback, hitting a function defined in my scope. AM I right in saying the scope should be for UI exposed purposes only? Is there a way to access the controller instance (rather than the scope) and utilize the 'this' keyword?

Comment: It's also not a good idea as it will break the orthogonality. So in my opinion, maybe other people wouldn't agree, the only way to comunicate from the DOM to the angular controller should be the scope or the directives. If anyway you are not confotable with this idea you can take advantage that you already have a $scope.analyticsIsReady and use a $watch on this variable http://jsfiddle.net/siliconball/nFnfQ/2/

Comment: Take a look on this page http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope . They say "Scope is the glue between application controller and the view" . If you think in an external javascript as a view then will it be the proper way?